# Please solve and explain

Tags: vbscript, qtp

This is a vbscript code. Please solve this and give me the reason.

```
a = 10
b =10
c = empty
d= empty
Msgbox a=b=c=d
```

Expected result False. 
Actual result True. Pls explain how.

Regards
Krishnan

Answer (score 4):

All comparison operators are evaluated from left to right and have the same precedence. The problem here is that "empty=false". If you want to check whether a var is really empty you have to use the isEmpty function. In a logical comparison empty=false.

Ergo your expression is evaluated:

```
1. a=b [true]
2. (a=b)=c [false] because c is empty and false
3. ((a=b)=c)=d  because d is false and 2. is false
```

Ergo false=false that is true ;-)

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for this. I was just having the doubt about how it makes a comparison between an empty and boolean value. Thank you anyways

Comment: @user2906636 If this answer was the one most useful, accept it so the answer is marked as "answered", and respect points :-) are granted.

Answer (score 0):

What you might consider trying is using something like this:

```
a = 10
b =10
c = empty
d= empty
Msgbox a=b AND a=c AND a=d
```

I think that the code that you have is causing an assignment rather than a comparison. Even though VBScript uses the = sign for both, an assignment will always return true.

Comment: No. An expression containing an "equals" sign always is a comparison in VBScript.